# Using Orchard CMS, How do I hide items in a container content type?

Tags: orchardcms

I have been attempting to hide the contained items of a Page content type.  I have been manipulating the placement.info file in my theme but I am not seeing the results I would expect.

Here's my bruit-force attempt:

```
  <Match Path="/about">
    <Match ContentType="Page">
      <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <Place Parts_Common_ContentItems="-"/>
        <Place Parts_Container_Contained="-"/>
        <Place Parts_Container_Contained_Summary="-"/>
        <Place Parts_Container_List="-"/>
      </Match>
    </Match>
  </Match>
```

I have scoured StackOverflow for the answer and I have used the Shape Tracing module to give me direction on designing my placement.info file but I still seem to be missing something.

Any pointers are appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you want to hide? What is the definition of your Page content type? By default, the Page content type does not contain a Container part...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I added the container and containable part to the Page content type.  The concept is to allow pages to have child pages.  So I might want my /about page to have child pages at /about/team and /about/contact.  However, I don't always want to display the contained item summaries.  Rather, I would like to put links to these pages in my menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say don't put it in the container if you don't want it to appear in there. You might also want to check out taxonomies, that provide a much better and flexible approach to classifying your contents.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide the content of a container using only Placement.info because the list is rendered by its own controller (`Orchard.Core.Containers.Controllers.ItemController`) instead of using a shape in the standard orchard shape rendering sytem.

However you may use your own (very simple) controller to build a display without this child list.